# Print coordinates in VB.NET or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing, area, margins

I have to print invoices from my software. I created the layout with Adobe Illustrator and saved it as a PNG image. My original idea was printing the layout as a background and then print the actual data taken from the database. I printed my layout inside my function and then I measured the various boxes of the layout for correctly placing my text. The problem is that my text is not printed in the correct position that I've found. I tried to change the margins to 0 but it seems to have no effect. I want this: if I choose to print my text line at x=10 mm and y=20mm the text must be phisically printed in this position without scaling/translating, also my background image.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using (e.g.) e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.**Milimeter**, and then simply specify the desired values using the [Graphics.DrawString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21kdfbzs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)